# How to prevent alt tags from showing whilst page is loading?

Tags: image, alt

I have many pages that contain a lot of images. How can one prevent the alt tags from showing as the images load?

Comment: you can try setting the DIV to none until the images load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the images be default hidden and show them using javascript when the document is ready.

Comment: For anyone who needs to know I used this jQuery to fade in the div when document is ready;  $(window).load(function() {
  // When the page has loaded
  $(".content").fadeIn(500);
});